# Trailing comma error in settings.json in VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, formatting, warnings, settings

I have recently set up VSCode in a different machine and I am receiving a lot of warnings stating 'trailing comma jsonc' in settings.json and workspaceSettings.json.

I cannot edit the default settings since they are a read-only file.

I have black as my default formatter.

Here's a couple screenshots of the warnings:
[image]
[image]

Thanks to anybody who helps!

Comment: Your line 4200 has a comma - remove it and see if you have less errors.  Line 4012 or 4013 might have the same.

Comment: I know, that's the problem, it says this is a read-only file and I cannot edit it therefore I can't delete these commas

Comment: I see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105414 where this bug may have been fixed in Insiders.  Can you test it there?